# Spring Security JDBC Authentication with Custom Username and Password Queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and trying to implement it in my application.
The database has already been established and has a different schema from the default.
The passwords have been hashed with an Oracle DB hashing scheme.

Here lies my problem.
I want to be able to pass custom queries to fetch the username and also has the incoming password before comparing it to what is in the database.
how do I go about that?

Comment: What have you tried, please post your code otherwise its hard to help you with the specifics

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the authentication logic by implementing custom `UserDetailsService` and overriding its `loadUserByUsername()` method.

```
public interface MembersService extends UserDetailsService {}

@Service
public class MembersServiceImpl implements MemberService{
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //custom logic to authenticate  
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found");
    }

}
```

Set this custom user details service in security configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private MembersService memberService;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(MembersService memberService) {
        this.memberService = memberService;
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.memberService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

}
```